# Is Ionic Framework Native Camera editable?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I'm new to ionic framework and i'm wondering, is it possible to put something into ionic framework's native camera? Like, put a label/tooltip that "detects" the color of the pixel? I'm currently working for my thesis project for color blind people.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with Ionic Native plugin. But code of this plugin is open source so you can add custom code to the plugin that reach your expectations and then use it in Ionic.

Comment: i'm sorry that i can't clearly understand your statement, but are you telling me that I can simply put something in the native camera using the code?

Comment: Let me explain. Camera is a native future of the operating system. So you need to call this native functionality somehow. Cordova is a wrapper that wraps your Javascript code to call camera future. On top of Cordova you have ionic native witch is typescript wrapper for Cordova pure JS code. So if you want to use future that isn’t implemented by someone else in Cordova You should implement this by your self. You need to write native code in Objective-C and Java for both platform, then wrap it to Cordova and then to Ionic Native.

Comment: your explanation pretty much sums up it. it is very much appreciated. i'll do my best to try it in the latter part